# SAS multiple large tables join - ERROR: Sort execution failure

Tags: sql, performance, sas

When running a large query of the form (using the undocuemnted `_method` to output the query method):

```
PROC SQL _method; CREATE TABLE output AS
SELECT
  t1.foo
  ,t2.bar
  ,t3.bat
  ,t4.fat
  ,t5.baa
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table t2
  ON t1.key2 = t2.key2
LEFT JOIN table3 t3
  ON t1.key3 = t3.key3
LEFT JOIN table t4
  ON t1.key4 = t4.key4
...
LEFT JOIN tablen tn
  ON t1.keyn = tn.keyn
;
```

Where `t1` is ca. 6 Gb, `t2` is a view on a table that is ca. 500 Gb, and `t3`, `t4` ... `tn` are each data tables ca. 1-10 Mb (there are typically six or seven of these), I run into the following error:

> NOTE: SAS threaded sort was used. ERROR: Sort execution failure.
>
> NOTE: View WORK.table2.VIEW used (Total process time):
>         real time           17:02.55
>         user cpu time       2:40.12
>                                                     The SAS System
>
> ```
>   system cpu time     2:19.41
>   memory              303785.64k
>   OS Memory           322280.00k
>   Timestamp           11/03/2014 08:13:25 PM
> ```

When I sample a very small % of `t1` to make it only ca. 30 Mb the query runs okay but even 10% of the table1 causes a similar issue.

**How can I profile this query?**

- to help me choose a better strategy
- to enable me to perform the operation on the whole dataset
- to limit the need for excessive I/O on the file system (i.e. I could process this batchwise and union the results)

Comment: Are the joins just looking up key values or might they be generating multiple rows?

Comment: They can actually be pulling multiple rows, yes.

Comment: What kind of box is this being run on?  How much available RAM?  Is t1-t2 a one to one or many to one/one to many relationship?

Comment: It's running on a virtual machine and I think it has ca. 32Gb memory. The disk with the libraries on has only ca. 100 Gb space remaining. The records in `t1` to `t2` and `t1` to `tn` are all many-to-one. If there are `m` records in `t1`, the `output` table has `m` rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is a really big set of data, and the problem may be with the view.  Second, if the data is in a database, you might want a pass-through query, so the processing is *all* done on the database side.

If the `left join`s are just looking up values, particularly individual values, you can rephrase the query as:

```
SELECT t1.foo,
       (SELECT t2.bar FROM table t2 WHERE t1.key2 = t2.key2) as bar,
       (SELECT t3.bat FROM table t3 WHERE t1.key3 = t3.key3) as bat,
       . . .
FROM table1 t1;
```

This should eliminate any possible sort that would occur on `table1`.

If the joins are returning multiple rows, this won't work; it will generate errors.

Comment: This looks like an excellent recommendation, I will give it a shot

Comment: I was using `bar`, `bat` etc. to represent multiple values from each lookup table. Can I return multiple values at a time in a similar fashion? Something like pseudo-code `(SELECT t2.bar, t2.bar2 FROM table t2 ON t1.key2 = t2.key2) AS bar, bar2`

Comment: @JustinJDavies . . . Alas, you cannot (in SAS).  If each of the smaller tables has an index on the key column, performance should be pretty good even with multiple subqueries.

Comment: I'm still testing trying to get this to work. I'm finding that I have to use the syntax `(SELECT t2.bar FROM table t2 WHERE t1.key2 = t2.key2) as bar` - using `WHERE` and not `ON`

Comment: @JustinJDavies . . . You are absolutely correct.  An `on` clause can only go in a `join`. That was a copy and paste error originally, I think.